# Using Sum inside a Case statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, case

I am having problem in MySQL adding three values, this should be simple right?

I have code that selects values from a column based upon the value of a second column, I use a case statement like this:

```
Select
        Max(Case
            When Table1.costcode Like '%Costcode1%' 
            Then Table1.costs 
            Else Null End) As 'Costcode1',
        Max(Case
            When Table1.costcode Like '%Costcode2%' 
            Then Table1.costs
            Else Null End) As 'Costcode2',
        Max(Case
            When Table1.costcode Like '%Costcode3%' 
            Then Table1.costs 
            Else Null End) As 'Costcode3',
        (Case
            When Table1.costcode In ('%Costcode1%','%Costcode2%','%Costcode3%')
            Then Sum(Table1.costs)
            Else Null End) As 'Total Cost',

From Table1
```

the first three Case statements work fine and all return values (these are held in the database as negative numbers e.g. -13624.00), however the Total Cost Case just returns Null...

The column Table1.costcode includes many other codes as well so I can't just sum all of the values without picking them out first.

It must be simple to sum these values, but obviously I'm missing something…  Help, please :-)

Thanks

Comment: Remove the extra comma after Total Cost.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo - the actual sql selects other things after this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    SUM(Case Table1.costcode
        When LIKE ('%Costcode1%') Then Table1.costs
        When LIKE ('%Costcode2%') Then Table1.costs
        When LIKE ('%Costcode3%') Then Table1.costs
        Then Table1.costs
        Else 0.00 End) As 'Total Cost'
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the column Table1.costs is of data type Decimal(10,2)

Comment: Edited it. Can you try with this?

Comment: Tried this option and still only getting 0.00 I'm afrid.

Comment: You are a STAR!  Thanks a million dude.

Comment: Thanks. After 3 attempts we finally get it. :-)

Comment: Okay, well I'm getting results but my comments where premature as the figures simply don't add up.  This is en example of one set of figures I'm getting back:  Costcode1='-20,778.00', Costcode2='-22,455.00', Costcode3='-6,924.00', Totalcost='-49,153,860.00'  The values of codes 1,2 and 3 are correct but Totalcost should be -50,157.  the figure I'm getting is 980 times to big. 980 doesn't represent any significant number on the figures either so I don't know where it's getting it's multiplier from.

Comment: Do you have values like Costcode10, Costcode11, Costcode12... or Costcode20, Costcode21, Costcode23... or Costcode30, Costcode31, Costcode32 in the costcode field?

Comment: Remove the % from the query and it will work. `When LIKE ('Costcode1') Then Table1.costs` make this change for all the 3.

Comment: Hi Juniad  the %s are there because some of the codes are preceeded by a space or 2 and some have a point at the end - it's a legacy problem with the data, initially the users manually entered the codes which have then been used from a drop down.  The client needs to cleans the data but that's another problem.  I will try and get the exact values including spaces or strip then out in the SQL.  Any which way thanks very much for your help with this challenge.

Comment: oh, and specifically, no the codes are not 30,31,32 etc.  just 3 but perhaps with a space after or a point.